# Parameter-Passing Methods

Tags: parameters, programming-languages, parameter-passing, pseudocode

I have been learning about Programming Languages in School, and my teacher was going over Parameter-Passing Methods, I could understand Call-by-Value and Call-by-Reference. However I am still not understanding how does call-by-result, copy-in-copy-out, call-by-name and call-by-need works.

I have here one example in pseudocode he gave us, I have the answers by I still can't figure out how it works.

```
void test() {
  int a[5]; 
  int i;
void f(int x) {
   a[i] = 9;
   i++;
   i = x;
}
  i = 1;
  a[1] = 7;
  a[2] = 4;
  f(a[i]);
// print i and a[1]
 }
```

what would the values on a[1] be through each call? I know a[2] would stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would help you understand better:

http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse505/99au/imperative/parameters.html